# Install has been stuck for a while

Tags: system-installation, dell

It's been a week and the install is not done. It is stuck at

```
Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source (i386)
```

for the last 6 days. What should I do?

Comment: I'd recommend you restart the install.

Comment: Ok was wondering if maybe I selected something I shouldn't of during install to cause this.

Comment: @JosephPearce What did you select. And has it really been a week?

Comment: Probably not. It seems like one of those times where it just hangs.

Comment: @JosephPearce Zach is right, just restart the instalation.

Comment: yes a week started it last Friday night. first time i did the install a few hours machine had 1 gig in it. ran slow. I went out bought more memory and redoing install because of no resource.list and nothing worked was told reinstall.